# Accessing Filtered Tableau Dashboards IDs with Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I need to download filtered tableau dashboards images as PNG.I am  using Python and tableauserverclient library .

But i did not understand the filtering hirearchy and how to get filtered dashboards ID , if i can get their IDs rest of the process is simple but important step is accessing the filtered  dashboards and how can i access ID of them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Share what you have tried otherwise we cannot help. The docs do have a section on how to pass filters to image request. https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#imagerequestoptions-class